# Reactive forms nested component not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have been trying to created nested reactive form components. I'm creating reusable input component for app inside reactive form. How to communicate with nested components in Reactive forms dynamically.

I tired, But I'm getting error,

> formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class)

**Parent HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="disciplineForm">

      <app-input-multilang [labelName]="Title" (childToParent)="update($event)" ></app-input-multilang>

    </form>
```

**Reusable comp: app-input-multilang HTML**

```
<ng-container>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="discipline">{{Title}}</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="control.name" id="discipline" required />
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-default active" type="button">de</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">en</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**Reusable comp: app-input-multilang TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor,FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,NG_VALIDATORS, } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-multilang',
  templateUrl: './form-input-multilang.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-input-multilang.component.scss'],

})
export class FormInputMultilangComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want divide a formGroup using child, you need pass or the formGroup itselft or the control. see [example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zbgak?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Your child can be like

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input formControlName="discipline"/>
</div>
//And has a @Input()
@Input() formGroup:FormGroup
```

Then your parent is like

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<child [formGroup]="myForm"></child>
</form>
<pre>
  {{myForm?.value|json}}
</pre>
```

OR you can pass only one control.

The child will be

```
<div >
  <input [formControl]="formControl"/>
</div>
//And has a @Input()
    @Input() formControl:FormControl
```

And the parent becomes

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <child2 [formControl]="myForm.get('mycontrol')"></child2 >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to add the formGroup directive to your child component. In your child component you delcared the form named `cForm` but you didn't add formGroup directive to your child component html. Add formGroup directive like this

```
 <ng-container>
  <form [formGroup]="cform">
     <div class="form-group">
  <label for="discipline">Discipline</label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="cname" id="discipline" required />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-default active" type="button">de</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">en</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </form> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It is not working. I want to validate the form from Parent control. Only input data validation should be component level.